# Button Background Color Animate

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, button, wpf-controls

I have around 30 buttons in my window and i want to change the background color of  one of them after some processes.

Here's my code :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
.
. //A Dialog Shows Up And Do Some Processes
.
Button b = (Button)sender;
ColorAnimation ca = new ColorAnimation();
ca.From = ((SolidColorBrush)b.Background).Color;
ca.To = Color.FromArgb(255, 132, 27, 13);
ca.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
ca.EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase();
b.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ca);
}
```

Some of my buttons are attached to this event. When this method runs and do it things, all the buttons with the same color as `sender`, begin the animation but i only want to `sender` runs the animation, not all of them. any solution to this ? maybe i'm using a wrong property to begin the animation with.

Comment: Add different SolidColorBrush instances to the Buttons' Backgrounds. One per Button. As a note, you don't need to set `ca.From`. It will automatically start from the current value.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the solution, worked, i was using a single brush for all the buttons , i changed it to `button.background = mybrush.Clone();` and fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new brush per button will solve your problem. The reason your buttons are sharing the animation is because `class`es are [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types#reference-types) in C#. When it is time to draw the buttons all buttons will notice the change the animation has made to the `Color` inside the brush they share. When you give each their own brush their brush will have their own color that can be animated independantly.
[image: Memory representation for value and reference types]